# Showing the selected datagrid cell on textBox29 but it throws an exception Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

i want to show the selected datagrid cell on textBox29 but it throws an exception Input string was not in a correct format

```
private void dataGridView5_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //when i click on a cell it carry a data to textBox29 

    textBox29.Text = dataGridView5.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
}

private void textBox29_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Discount is a function which is on textbox29 that take discount 
    //of the data which is clicked from datagrid

    discount();
}

private void textBox28_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    discount();
}

public void discount()
{
    //this is my discount function i want to show the selected datagrid cell on 
    //textBox29 but it throws an exception Input string was
    //not in a correct format.

    Double d;
    Double di;
    Double i;
    d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox29.Text);
    i = Convert.ToDouble(textBox28.Text);
    di = -((d * 100.0) / i) + i;
    textBox23.Text = di.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You don't care about meaningful control names, do you?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: Place a break point in `private void dataGridView5_MouseClick(...)` on `textbox29.Text=...`... What is the value you are trying to do `ToString();` ? Is it `null` maybe?

Comment: no value is not null but type of that value is string @alykins

Comment: What is the value of `dataGridView5.SelectedCells[0].Value` ?

Comment: value of the selectedCell from datagridview5 is 24  @alykins

Comment: every things is ok with program but when data from datagridview5 populate to textbox29 it throws an exception @alykins

Comment: d = Convert.ToDouble(textBox29.Text); it is my textBox29 code @alykins

Comment: Oh ok, so the problem isn't in the population of textbox29, that goes ok... it is in the conversion of the text to double that the error is happening on, yes?

Comment: Throw a breakpoint on `d=Convert.ToDouble(textBox29.Text);` and when it hits that breakpoint, before stepping through, in the immediate window type `?textBox29.Text` and what is the value of it? If you try to convert to a double from a `"";` or a `" ";` or a `string.Empty;` you will get the exact same error message you posted. A null value will not throw that error.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rz2YGvs.png sir this is my screen shot can u watch it @alykins

Comment: The screen shot you posted shows `i = Convert.ToDouble(textBox28.Text);` as throwing the error, and then if you look at the watch window, `textBox28.Text` value is `""` which from above comment, will throw that error- essentially you have been looking at the wrong box throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your screen shot, the error is happening on this line

```
i = Convert.ToDouble(textBox28.Text);
```

and then the value of `textBox28.Text` is `""`. This will throw the format error as the string is not a valid number [see details in this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k(v=vs.110).aspx)

More importantly is that you have two separate text boxes triggering the same event, and that is okay, except you do not check the values of the text to verify they are not empty. You can solve this a number of ways, maybe the easiest would be to throw in a

```
i = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i)? 0:Convert.ToDouble(i);
```

And then the same thing for textBox29 as well. The design for this could use some optimization, but this should put you back on the right path.